# jquery and javascript if...else problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I've been trying to figure this one out for some time now, but no luck.

I use simplest jquery and ajax to load content into my page when navigation bar or sidebar links are clicked. I simply put this in document.ready:

```
$("#nav ul li a").click(function(){content_load($(this).attr('href'));return false;});
```

My content_load function is this:

```
function content_load(toLoad)
  {
  $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
  function loadContent() 
    {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',function(){showNewContent();tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');});  
    }  
    function showNewContent()
      {  
      $('#content').show('fast');
      }  
   }
```

This works!

But...when I put simple if...else statement in function_load(), instead of simple ajax load, I get navigated to the page I wanted to load with load() function. It's like "return false" is ignored...

So this is the code that "breaks" everything:

```
function content_load(toLoad)
  {
  if(toLoad=="content/page1.html") {//do something}
  else
    { 
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
    function loadContent() 
      {  
      $('#content').load(toLoad,'',function(){showNewContent();tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');});  
      }  
      function showNewContent()
        {  
        $('#content').show('fast');
        }  
     }
   }
```

Any idea why???

Thanks!
Newman

Comment: Well I know this is always a matter of taste, but that indentation style is really hard to read.

Comment: What is `function_load`?

Comment: Ya DO know that the {// do something} comments OUT the close bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a weird scope problem. Put the functions outside the `if...else` statement, or even better, use anonymous functions:

```
function content_load(toLoad) {
   if(toLoad=="content/page1.html") {
      //do something
   }
   else { 
      $('#content').hide('fast', function() {
         $(this).load(toLoad, function() {
             $(this).show('fast');
             tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');
         });
      });
   }
}
```

That you are redirected to the page means that your function errors somewhere. If you have code where you have `//do something`, you should examine it too.

The error console of your browser should give you at least *some* information.

---

Instead of `return false` you can also call the appropriate methods of the event object:

```
$("#nav ul li a").click(function(event){
    // event.preventDefault();  <-- put here to always prevent reload, 
    //                              even on error (but should be avoided)
    content_load(this.href);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This works!!! Thanks you so much! It seems there was some scope problem. You saved my day ;)

Comment: @Newman: You're welcome :) Actually I'm not sure why, but I know that Firefox treats functions created in control statements differently. In which browser did you test it? Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the tick outline next to it ;)

Comment: Iceweasel :)  I also changed "return false" to "e.preventDefaul()"...so I guess that's it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Newman: Well, that could be it. Afaik Iceweasle is more or less Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

is it that your comment in first line commenting out the closing brace of your if statement

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that's a typo but the closing parentheses is commented out.

```
//do something}
```

That will cause it to break

Comment: yes, I would suggest deleting everything and just putting an if else statement with alerts in each branch - alert('inside if branch') and alert('inside else branch'). We will then see if the return false works(which it should).

Comment: Already tried it, this also works. In this it doesn't navigate to the other page, it just pops up the alert. It's really strange, as I said, it seems like that "return false" gets ignored. I don't know...

Comment: can you have a function within a function in js?

Comment: Well, it works without if-else. And these are callback functions, dont know any other way to use them...

Comment: wow! you learn new things every day!! What is the advantage of this?

Comment: Have you tried Felix Kling's solution Newman? It seems like the best way forward?

Comment: @The_Butcher: If you need a function only one time or at one place, there is no need to pollute the global namespace. You can also write quite dynamic code.

Comment: so that function exists only in that scope?

Comment: You're asking someone who heard about jquery 5 days ago :) I guess my explanation is not going to be a good one, but in jquery callback functions are called after the original function is executed. So, if you want to give 2 functions as an argument to some other jquery function, you can open a function()  statement and call those 2 functions. I don't know if I explained it correctly...but any jquery tutorial explains this much better :)

Comment: @The_Butcher: Exactly. You can try it: `function A(){ function B() { alert('foo');} B();}; A(); B(); // second B() doesn't work as it is outside of A`.

Comment: @Felix - Great! Thanks a lot man!
@Newman - Well for 5 days only you're doing well man :)

Comment: @The_Butcher: Yeah, but my eyes and nerves aren't ;)